# iGraph figures chopped off in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, igraph

I have some code that generates layouts for the following minimum spanning tree "cell_dtree":

```
> cell_dtree
IGRAPH 951dfd5 D--- 720 719 -- 
+ edges from 951dfd5:
  [1] 400->  1   1->  2  38->  3   3->  4 197->  5  10->  6  10->  7  13->  8   1->  9  28-> 10 225-> 11 362-> 12  30-> 13
 [14]  20-> 14 148-> 15   3-> 16  13-> 17 160-> 18 435-> 19   1-> 20  60-> 21  38-> 22   9-> 23  68-> 24   9-> 25 178-> 26
 [27]  21-> 27   1-> 28  60-> 29   2-> 30   1-> 31   2-> 32   1-> 33 352-> 34  21-> 35  20-> 36   1-> 37   1-> 38 554-> 39
 [40]   3-> 40 554-> 41 333-> 42 352-> 43 126-> 44   1-> 45  69-> 46 227-> 47 160-> 48   1-> 49   1-> 50  37-> 51 708-> 52
 [53] 705-> 53 185-> 54 307-> 55  48-> 56 667-> 57 563-> 58 428-> 59 519-> 60 428-> 61 707-> 62   1-> 63 707-> 64 707-> 65
 [66] 707-> 66 214-> 67  20-> 68  68-> 69  37-> 70 453-> 71  57-> 72 148-> 73 345-> 74  69-> 75 148-> 76  80-> 77  79-> 78
 [79]   9-> 79  70-> 80  68-> 81 148-> 82  23-> 83 345-> 84 454-> 85 345-> 86  36-> 87 345-> 88  36-> 89 311-> 90 148-> 91
 [92]  13-> 92 345-> 93  13-> 94 350-> 95 326-> 96  79-> 97 666-> 98 539-> 99 430->100 554->101 213->102  20->103  38->104
[105]  21->105 172->106 112->107   1->108  20->109 453->110  80->111 703->112  20->113   9->114  79->115   1->116  47->117
+ ... omitted several edges
```

Here is the r markdown code to create the plot.

````
    ```{r, results='asis', fig.width = 7, fig.heigt = 7}
    set.seed(1)
    l2 <- igraph::layout.lgl(cell_dtree)
    l2 <- igraph::layout.norm(l2, ymin = -2, ymax = 2, xmin = -2, xmax = 2)
    plot(cell_dtree, 
     rescale = F,
     layout = l2 * 1,
     edge.arrow.width=0.1,
     vertex.label=NA,
     vertex.size=1,
     vertex.label=NA,
     edge.width=0.5,
     edge.arrow.size=0.5,
     edge.arrow.width=0.7)
    ```
````

When this document goes through knittr, the plot looks like it has been cut off, only a rectangular region in the center is displayed in the knitr html output.

[image: ![enter image description here]

To troubleshoot the issue, I ran igraph's implementation of Erdos-Renyi graph, using the same number of vertices (720) as the graph above, and the same plotting parameters:

````
    ```{r, results='asis', out.width = '100%', out.height = '100%', fig.width = 7, fig.heigt = 7}
er <- igraph::sample_gnm(n=720, m=40) 
plot(er, vertex.size=6, vertex.label=NA)  
set.seed(1)
l2 <- igraph::layout.lgl(er)
l2 <- igraph::layout.norm(l2, ymin = -2, ymax = 2, xmin = -2, xmax = 2)
plot(er, 
     rescale = F,
     layout = l2 * 1,
     vertex.label=NA,
     vertex.size=1,
     vertex.label=NA,
     edge.width=0.5,
     edge.arrow.size=0.5,
     edge.arrow.width=0.7)
```
````

However, the resulting image does exactly what I want it to do: fill the figure box in an efficient way without those big white borders.  Obviously not all the vertices are displayed here, but the scaling helps to show that the layout is using all available space for the image:

[image]

Comment: I do not think you need `results="asis"` for `igraph`

Comment: Please make sure your question is fully reproducible for others. We do not have access to `mapped$similarity_graph` `cell_mst` etc.  This makes it very difficult to help as we can only guess what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHarper, I have added a summary of the object that is being plotted (my own data) and also an example of the parameters being applied to an igraph-generated data set.